# How can I generate a random unique User id value in django user model and show it on django admin?

Tags: python, django

I have a Model in Django. I just extended the AbstractBaseUser and added some custom fields in the with BaseUserManager.

Now I need to generate a unique Id as primary key and need to show it on Django admin. How can I do that? My model is given below.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin,BaseUserManager



class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self, email, password, first_name, last_name, mobile, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Email must be provided")
        if not password:
            raise ValueError('Password is not provided')

        user = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
            mobile = mobile,
            **extra_fields
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password, first_name, last_name, mobile, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff',True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active',True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser',False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, first_name, last_name, mobile, password, 
**extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, first_name, last_name, mobile, 
**extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff',True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active',True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser',True)
        return self._create_user(email, password, first_name, last_name, mobile, 
 **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
    
    email = models.EmailField(db_index=True, unique=True, max_length=254)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=240)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField( max_length=250)

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=True) 
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True) 
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False) 

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name','last_name','mobile']

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'User'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Users'
```

Comment: Use uuid module for generating unique id

Comment: where should I change it in my code? please give me an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've set [**`DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field) inside your **settings.py** then you don't have to set primary key for your **User** model django will add it automaticaly you can read about it [**`primary_key`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#primary-key)
but if you're willing to add custom id's to your **User** model then you can use [**`UUIDField`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield) like this

```
import uuid
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin

class User(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    # other fields
```

Comment: it is showing me error like    ValidationError at /admin/
['“1” is not a valid UUID.']

Comment: I think you've data inside your db try to flush db or delete it